# Google API message shown in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api

I am try to fetch the User Information through Google API, but
I got the following error:

```json
error: {
    errors: [
    {
    domain: "usageLimits",
    reason: "accessNotConfigured",
    message: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
    }
    ],
    code: 403,
    message: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
    }
}
```

**My code is as follow:**

```
-(void)get_real_profile:(NSString*)userid
{
    // POST parameters
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/%@?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",userid]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [urlRequest setValue:userid forHTTPHeaderField:@"userId"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data,
                                               NSError *connectionError) {

                               NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                               NSLog(@"%@",json);
                           }];
}
```

I am not Enable the billing for this App. So, Is there any issue regarding the billing is disabled?

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into https://code.google.com/apis/console‎
2. click on `APIs and Auth`
3. Enable the relevant API that you want to access
4. Be sure that you are enabling it for the project that you are accessing from the code. The active project is displayed above the `overview` link